# Running stored procedure with out parameter and saving out value to variable in sqlworkbench/j script

Tags: sql-workbench-j

How do I save procedure out parameter value to variable for later reuse in sqlworkbench/j script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to run a stored procedure with out parameters using `WbCall`

However, the result of that can not be used to be stored into a Workbench variable.

That is only possible with "regular" queries (`SELECT`) that return a result set.